# Filebeat vs Directly pushing logs to logstash from application

Tags: java, python-3.x, logstash, filebeat

I am planning to architect a centralized logging system for one of our project which has multiple components written in Java, Python & Scala. I want to collect logs from different parts ( REST Server, Spark Jobs, Airflow server ) to logstash and index into Elastic search. I could see there are direct libraries in both [Python](https://pypi.org/project/python-logstash/) & [Java](https://github.com/mp911de/logstash-gelf) logging modules to push logs directly to logstash from application. And I could see filebeat which can be configured on servers to push logs to logstash from files. What is the advantage of having filebeat rather than sending logs directly to logstash? What is the best practice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are a few pros and cons of both approaches:

### Application Logs => Logstash

**Pros:**

- Lesser components to manage and straight forward pipeline

**Cons:**

- Congestion at Logstash or its outage may adversely affect your application
- Changes to log destination may require you to redeploy or restart your application

### Application Logs => Filebeat => Logstash

**Pros:**

- Filebeat is a lightweight utility which allows you to decouple your log processing from application logic
- Change of log destination is a breeze, and it natively supports load-balancing among multiple instances of logstash destinations
- Logs can be enriched with additional fields, or you can perform conditional processing of logs just by changing filebeat configurations, e.g. send logs for customer A to Logstash A
- Logs are buffered locally and will be reliably transferred to Logstash even if logstash process gets restarted or becomes unavailable for a certain amount of time (Provided your log files remain on the disk to be consumed by filebeat and has appropriate configs)

**Cons:**

- Another component to manage in your application architecture
- Requires additional system resources (usually does very lightweight processing)

Comment: Thanks @Furhan S. Make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Filebeat and other beats can directly send the message to ES but there are addition advantages while using logstash.

1. you can use filters in logstash based on inputs.
2. It support Grok filter and other filter plugins like csv , xml and many more.
3. It supports multiple codecs
4. you can use logstash as single point to control all pipelines
5. logstash can be monitored via Kibana GUI.
6. Logstash management is easy and can be performed via Kibana GUI.
7. Filebeat only support files as input but logstash support large array on inputs type

Comment: Thanks for reply. We defenitly have logstash in place. Question is about how to send logs to logstash. Should we use filebeat or log things directly to logstash using logger modules in Java & Python.

Comment: you should first send to filebeat and from filebeat to logstash. filebeat also preserve the state of file read and if filebeat restarted it start reading from last position.

Comment: Writing to files is a free, distributed cache.  If ES, LS, or FB are down or degraded, your files will act as a buffer.